# Localization for rejected migrated posts

Tags: bug, status-completed, 10k-tools, localization, russian-stackoverflow

As far as I see the sentence *"post deleted"* is not able to localize in the [rejected migrated posts section](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tools/posts/migrated/rejected) of the 10k tools:

> [image: post deleted]

Nevertheless "post deleted" already has [translation](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/79591988?key=00249643e3e9863cb863ad941719dcae) in transifex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That needed a bit of code changes, having the translation in Transifex was not enough. It's fixed now.